# Is it possible to have safe mutable aliasing to non-overlapping memory?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a way to take a large object and break it into smaller mutable child objects, which can be processed in parallel.

Something like:

```
struct PixelBuffer { data:Vec<u32>, width:u32, height:u32 }
struct PixelBlock { data:Vec<u32> }
impl PixelBuffer {
  fn decompose(&'a mut self) -> Vec<Guard<'a, PixelBlock>>> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Where the resulting `PixelBlock`'s can be processed in parallel, and the parent `PixelBuffer` will remain locked until all `Guard<PixelBlock>` are dropped.

This is effectively mutable pointer aliasing; the large data block in `PixelBuffer` will be directly modified via each `PixelBlock`.

However, each `PixelBlock` is non-overlapping segment from the internal data in `PixelBuffer`.

You can certainly do this in unsafe code (internal buffer is a raw pointer; generate a new external pointer for each `PixelBlock`); but is it possible to achieve the same result using safe code?

(NB. I'm open to using a data block allocated from libc::malloc if that'll help?)

Comment: If the memory is non-overlapping, is it really aliasing? As I understand it, *aliasing* means two different names referring to the same thing, like two variables pointing to the same memory.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not sure. Technically there's a pointer to the start of the data block, and a pointer to the sub-section of it. That's ... technically... aliasing? Maybe?

Comment: For example, if I have a Vec<Foo>, it's aliasing if I write to both the first and 3rd items in it at the same time, even though they don't overlap in memory, right?

Comment: No, it's definitely not aliasing. As I said in my answer, the mutable iterators already do all of this.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)): "modifying the data through one name implicitly modifies the values associated with all aliased names"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine and is a natural consequence of how, e.g., iterators work: the `next` method hands out a sequence of values that are not lifetime-connected to the reference they come from, i.e. `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>`. This automatically means that any iterator that yields `&mut` pointers (like, `slice.iter_mut()`) is yielding pointers to non-overlapping memory, because anything else would be incorrect.

One way to use this in parallel is something like my `simple_parallel` library, e.g. [`Pool::for_`](http://huonw.github.io/simple_parallel/simple_parallel/pool/struct.Pool.html#method.for_).

(You'll need to give more details about the internals of `PixelBuffer` to be more specific about how to do it in this case.)

Comment: Technically though, how would you safely hand the child items out though? For example, take the trivial example of the internal data being a Vec<u8>; you can't safely take two mutable slices from this right? The reason Vec can do it internally is that it uses an unsafe pointer internally, as I understand it?

Comment: You just need to do something that allows the compiler to understand that the pointers are disjoint. At the lowest level this involves `unsafe`, but you can also build on existing functionality, like `split_at_mut` and iterators over mutable references.

Comment: @Doug it's exposed through `split_at_mut` in the library. Sure, it's not implemented with language primitives (instead with a block of `unsafe` marked code), but theoretically it could be.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to completely avoid unsafe Rust, because the compiler cannot currently evaluate the safety of sub-slices. However, the standard library contains code that provides a safe wrapper that you can use.

Read up on [`std::slice::Chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Chunks.html) and [`std::slice::ChunksMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.ChunksMut.html).

Sample code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ceec5be3e1530c0a6d3b&version=stable

However, your next problem is sending the slices to separate threads, because the best way to do that would be `thread::scoped`, which is currently deprecated due to some safety problems that were discovered this year...

Also, keep in mind that `Vec<_>` owns its contents, whereas slices are just a view. Generally, you want to write most functions in terms of slices, and keep only one "Vec" to hold the data.